# Maven dependencies SVN build number

Tags: maven

I've checked these two plugins to get the last SVN revision number: [svn-revision-number-maven-plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-svn-revision-number-plugin/) and [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/index.html). They work fine but now I need to get the last SVN revision for the dependencies' of my multi-module web-application. I hoped to include an extra entry to the pom.properties file in META-INF for each dependency by overriding the construction of this file but I haven't succeeded. I haven't found how to even change the contents of it. Or maybe there is any way to put an extra properties file which can be filtered?

**Update:** my goal is to get the dependencies revision number at runtime in my web-application.

Comment: I've found the related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096279/turn-off-buildnumber-maven-plugin-for-submodules
Still trying to retrieve this info from my exploded WAR.

Comment: Why do you need the revision number if you have `tags` in SVN. And what are the versions in maven are intended. They represent the SVN/Git Tag. So why do you need the revision number?

Comment: @khmarbaise I should have mentioned it - I want to get this info at runtime in my web-application.

Comment: You can use the same information at run-time.

Comment: I have some SNAPSHOT versions of my dependencies. So to get the state of them I need to know the SVN revision number.

Comment: You can use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/unlock-snapshots-mojo.html) to pin the SNAPSHOT to particular timestamp versions. After the release you don't need the SNAPSHOT versions anymore.